# How to take user input when it is seperated by any number of spaces and line breaks in python?

Tags: python-3.x, input, python-3.6

I have been trying to take integer inputs seperated by any number of white spaces or line breaks. I know how to take space seperated outputs and outputs having line breaks. In C based languages we don't have to care about where the input is, it automatically takes the input when found, but I don't think this is the case with Python(correct me if I am wrong). Can anybody help?

I tried using a While statement till True and using a `try` statement in it. But it doesn't work.

```
a = []
try:
    while(True):
        a.append(int(input()))
except:
    pass
print(a)
```

when i input

`12   12
12`

it returns an empty list. If i remove the int in the input it returns a list `[12   12, 12]`.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: So, you want it to continuously accept input, but only if it's an int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this: The Shortest way possible**

```
a = []
s=input()

while s != '':  
    i = s.split()       
    [a.append(int(j)) for j in i]
    s=input()

print(a)
```

**Input:**

```
1 2 3
4 5
6
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

***You can also try:***

```
a = []
s=input()

while s != '':  
    i = s.split()       
    a.extend(map(lambda s: int(s),i))
    s=input()

print(a)
```

Comment: This works, specifically for integers.  I just realized the entire time I was trying to make one that would accept any input, when OP specifically said it was for integers. I feel like a dork.

Comment: Yes i specifically converted the input numbers to integers i thought that's what you wanted

Comment: That is what they wanted. I was the first answerer, and I spent the better part of an hour brainstorming to figure out how to also support strings.

Comment: Please accept the ans if that's what you wanted? @MegaEmailman :)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not OP. That would be @T.P.

Comment: oh sry my bad :0

Comment: Thanks Man :), appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194531/discussion-between-chetan-vashisth-and-megaemailman).

Answer (score 1):

Wait, so I think I understand it now. You want to accept any amount of input, but save each input separated by whitespace as its own entry?  There is actually a string method for that. Here's an example script for it. It's not the best, but it demonstrates the method pretty well.

```py
list = []
string = "user input goes here"
splitString = string.split()
for word in splitString:
    list.append(word)
print(list)
```

Output:

```
["user", "input", "goes", "here"]
```

The string.split() method uses space by default, but you can specify another delimiter like the # sign.

```py
List = []
String = "Hi#my#name#is#bob"
newString = String.split("#")
for word in newString:
    list.append(word)
```

EDIT:  Here is a full working implementation that will work whether the thing separating two inputs is whitespace, newlines, or anything else you'd like.

```py
import re
list = []
while True:
    string = input()
    if string == "break":
        break
    splitString = re.split("[\s | \r\n]", string)
    for word in splitString:
        list.append(word)
    cleanList = []
    for word in list:
        if word != '':
            cleanList.append(word)
print(cleanList)
```

Input:

```
12 94 17
56
3
```

Output:

```
[12, 94, 17, 56, 3]
```

Functional proof: Click [here](https://youtu.be/vckGvVNrFL0)

Comment: I get where you're going. But string.split("\r\n") would make it accept input after newlines as well.

Comment: And yeah, comments can't have line breaks. It's rough.

Comment: i think this code will accept only the input in one line but not from next lines(i.e. involving line breaks). if my input is something like this ;12   3  (next line) 32   12 (next line) 3.; this code will only accept 12 and 3 and append them to the list and simply the input in the next line. Thanks

Comment: I can edit my answer to have a full working implementation if you'd like?

Comment: the fact that when the input will be seperated by spaces and when it will be seperated by '\n' is not known is posing me problem. I just dont know the way in python.

Comment: If that works, could you please accept the answer as correct to help other people find it?

Comment: this code is not working @MegaEmailman . I am  getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Thanks for the response, but in line 4 of your code, splitString is already a list of strings(because of the split method), a split method cant be used on a string, thus it shows an error on line 5, the error statement reads: '''list' object has no attribute 'split' ''

Comment: and one more thing that ,there is no breaking point in the above code....

Comment: There was none in his either so I assumed he just wanted an example and would insert the breaking point himself. Also, I fixed the issue with line 4 there!  I wasn't at my computer to test at the time, but now I am, and it works like a charm.

Comment: Changed it out for a much better answer with a break keyword when the user enters break as their input.

Comment: I have now edited in a link to a video showing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you will some insight in this example & have added my personal view of how to code.

Firstly, giving input with multi-spaces is understandable but not multi-lines. Prefer taking input one by one.

For testing & debugging purposes, prefer separate collecting user and processing input data.

Now, say you have collected your user input and stored as **data** using `raw_input`, which is handy when you need to collect multiline inputs. Please explore `raw_input`, it is supported in Python3 and Python2.

```
>>>
>>> data = '''12
...
... 12       12
...
...
... 12'''
>>> data
'12 \n\n12       12\n\n\n12'
>>> print(data)
12

12       12


12
```

### step1: clear all line separations

```
>>> double_spaces = '  '
>>> single_space = ' ' 
>>> data = data.strip().replace('\n', single_space)
>>> data
'12   12       12   12'
```

### step2: Fix multiple spaces

```
>>> while double_spaces in data:
...     data = data.replace(double_spaces, single_space)
...
>>> data
'12 12 12 12'
>>> print(list(map(int, data.split()))
...
... )
[12, 12, 12, 12]
>>>
```

## **Problems with you code**

```
>>> a = []
>>> try:
...     while(True):
...         a.append(int(input()))
... except:
...     pass
...
12
1
12  12
>>> a
[12, 1]
>>>
```

When you enter `12   12`, below is supposed to happen.

```
>>> int('12 12')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12 12'
```

Since this code had bad exception handling `except:`, your use case is returning an empty list as expected.

Since I have changed the input, you see this difference.